# MD5 for my java hashcode which is int 32 bits

Tags: java, hash

I am looking to implement my ConsistentHashing to which I can supply a good HashingFunction. A decent implementation using a SortedMap is explained here: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/tomwhite/archive/2007/11/consistent_hash.html

Now like suggested on the post I would like to use a Crypto function like MD5 which has good randomization. I understand MD5 gives back an inherent 128 bit output, however I need a randomized 32 bits. Would the following have high cardinality?

(1)  Would the first 4 bytes of MD5 output be random enough? In which case I could just take first 32 bits of 128 bits of MD5 hash:

```
   class MD5Hashing implements HashFunction{
        @Override
        public int getHash(String key) throws Exception{
                MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] byteArray = digest.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
                return buffer.getInt()& 0x7fffffff;
        }
    }
```

(2) What if I use just the String's internal Horner's algorithm which uses 31x+y on all characters in String?

```
class StringHashing implements HashFunction{
    @Override
    public int getHash(String key) throws Exception{
        return key.hashCode()& 0x7fffffff; 
    }
}
```

(3) My internal Consistent Hashing like in link above is just a TreeMap Should I be using a BigInteger instead to still be able to get all 128 bits from MD5 or other Crypto algorithm?

```
private final SortedMap<Integer, T> circle = new TreeMap<Integer, T>();
```

EDIT:
Looks like both are bad, I even tried taking the last 4 bytes from MD5 hash. buffer.getInt(12).

Running for 5000 random strings following was the distribution. 
{host4.a.b.com=1599, host3.a.b.com=1075, host2.a.b.com=238, host1.a.b.com=2088}

Comment: The word is 'algorithm'. It is derived from somebody's name. It isn't appropriate to abbreviate it.

Answer (score 0):

Found Murmur hash which has API to convert String input to a 32 bit hash output. Gave me a very nice distribution as well.

{host4.a.b.com=1665, host3.a.b.com=1373, host2.a.b.com=648, host1.a.b.com=1314}

```
http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/~holub/sw/javamurmurhash/
public static int hash32( final String text) {...}
```